# What is the equivalent in Tensorflow 2.0 of tf.contrib.framework.nest.flatten_dict_items()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm upgrading TF1 code to TF2 with the tf_upgrade_v2, and I found this message:

```
tf.contrib.framework.nest.flatten_dict_items(dict)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'
```

How I should update the code? I didn't find a solution.

Comment: Try `tf.python.util.nest.flatten_dict_items`.

Answer (score 1):

This one is a little odd (hard to find) because it's not exported in the same way as the core functionality.

cs95 is correct in his comment in as much that it lives in `tensorflow.python.util.nest` but one cannot simply do:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

tf.python.util.nest.flatten_dict_items(my_dict)
```

Instead, we need to import the `nest` module itself with something like:

```py
from tensorflow.python.util import nest

nest.flatten_dict_items(my_dict)
```

Comment: It works, but I have a question. Why can't we do as cs95 says? I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not the best authority on how python imports and exports work. I happen to know (borne out by experience) is that only the methods marked `tf.export()` get imported when we just import the *base* tf module. The 'why' (or more concretely, the mechanismm by which) this happens isn't something I've got an answer on I'm afraid.